# It'll perform checks "on" or "in" itself?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct and why:

> It'll perform checks on itself

or

> It'll perform checks in itself

I'm writing about a computer system that is going to perform checks in order to make sure it's not being modified.

Comment: Both are suspect.  What is your context?

Comment: I'm writing about a computer system that is going to perform checks in order to make sure it's not being modified

Comment: It will check itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is correct; the second is incorrect. 
This is because 'check (up)' can be used with 'on' preceding an object (not 'in' or 'at' or another preposition).

E.g. I'll check (up) on you tomorrow = I'll see how you're doing.

Comment: I can _check in_ to my flight at the airport.